# Passing defines to function

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, atmel

I'm programming with an AVR and I'm trying to create a function to set a pin as an output. I made a struct to hold the Register and Pin number like this:

```
typedef struct Pin{
    uint8_t pinNo;
    volatile uint8_t* pinReg;
};
```

I then have this function to set a pin an output.

```
void pin_output(struct Pin pin){
    //DDRA |= _BV(DDA6); 
    *(pin.pinReg) |= _BV(pin.pinNo);
}
```

Called like this:

```
struct Pin pin6;
pin6.pinNo = DDA6;
pin6.pinReg = DDRA; 
pin_output(pin6);
```

This works fine but the led brightness very dim. If I set the output like this:

```
DDRA |= _BV(DDA6);
```

The pin is at its expect brightness about 3-5x more bright then with the function. What is getting lost in the function causing the problem with the brightness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently macro `DDRA` hides some sort of *lvalue* tied to some hardware register. Changing that lvalue changes the register and the brightness. If the actual type if that lvalue is `uint8_t`, then in order to pass it through your `struct Pin` you should initialize the corresponding member of your struct as

```
pin6.pinReg = &DDRA;
```

Note the `&` operator.

The `pin6.pinReg = DDRA` that you have in your code should not even compile or at least should produce warnings for incompatible types in assignment.

Comment: Sorry that was some debug code left over. I updated question. I assigned pin6.pinReg as you said but the brightness is still dim.

Comment: @Nick: There's no reason for it not to work. Once you add that `&` it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb. I updated the question code and just assumed I updated the actual code and did not... haha. Thanks works great now.